# compare vector with other kind of container in stl?

Tags: c++

compare vector with other kind of container in stl?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `std::equal()` from `<algorithm>`.

Something like:

```
if ((vect.size() == otherContainer.size()) && 
    std::equal( vect.begin(), vect.end(), otherContainer.begin()) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that if the other container doesn't have enough elements `std::equal()` won't work (undefined behavior), hence the check for `size()` which you may or may not really need if you already know that there are enough elements in the other container.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the other answers will allow you to compare for equality, but if you want a "character-by-character" compare, you should use [`std::lexographical_compare`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lexicographical_compare/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [std::equal](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/equal.html) algorithm to do this.

Answer (score -1):

A vector implements a dynamic resizable array, a list implements a linked list, and a deque implements something like a hybrid of those. Containers like set, map, multiset and multimap are associative. Besides those, there are container adaptors like queue, priority_queue and stack. A vector can be used as an underlying type of the last two.